# Is there a `git cp` command that can copy only tracked files, like `svn cp`?

Tags: git, svn

Unlike Subversion, git has no `cp` command. For files, this is not a problem: if I want to copy a file `a` to `b`, I can just do:

```
cp -a a b
git add b
```

However, say I want to copy a directory `d` to give it another name `e`. I can still do the same thing. However, `d` may contain files that are not tracked by git, e.g., compiled binaries, etc. In this context, I do not want to do the above, because I do not want git to track these additional files.

With Subversion, I can do `svn cp`, and it will only copy and add the files that are tracked by Subversion. **How can I do this with git?**

Answer (score 4):

You can use git clone:

```
$ git clone /path/to/project /target/path
```

Then remove the .git file

```
$ rm -R /target/path/.git
```

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks! but this only works for entire repositories, not for subdirectories of a repository, which is the use case I had in mind.

Comment: That's right but after copy the entire repository, you can copy the files you wanted to copy before. They will not contain any ignored folders of files.

Comment: Yes that's right, but when copying a smaller subfolder of a large repository to a different folder of this same repository, it's a bit inefficient and annoying to go elsewhere, clone the whole repo, retrieve the right subfolder, move it in place, delete the reste, and move back to where you where. So I think that's a nice trick but not for all use cases.

Comment: if you clone like that then it's much simpler and faster to use `git worktree`. Imagine the time saving on a huge 10-100GB repo when `git worktree` is almost "instant"

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the tree hash of "d" (git ls-tree HEAD d)
2. git read-tree -u --prefix=e tree-hash

Done!

`git read-tree` lets you replace your index, or (as in this case) a subtree of it, with any tree object that you know the hash of.  The `-u` checks out the subtree from the index afterwards (as if you had done `git checkout -- e`).
For more information about tree objects and the index, please see the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Can you explain *how* this works?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Here's a one liner based on this answer: `git read-tree -u --prefix=$destination $(git ls-tree --format='%(objectname)' HEAD $source)` - How this works: It retrieves the hash of the source directory from Git's object database, and adds the tree addressed by that hash to both the index and the worktree at the desired destination. IOW, the new files are already staged after running this command.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is simply to make sure that all untracked files are ignored in `.gitignore`.

In this case, when you copy the directory with `cp -Ra d e` and run `git add e` on the copy, git will be smart enough to avoid adding the files that it ignores.

Answer (score 1):

An example command flow for what the OP wants to do in windows 10 is as follows

```
git archive -o d.zip HEAD:d
move d d_original
tar -x -f d.zip
move d e
move d_original d
```

In the commands above

1. we use `git archive` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)) to create a zip of the folder `d` as it is committed in the git tree
2. rename `d` to `d_original` as we will extract the previously zipped `d` folder and we do not want it to overwrite our current `d` folder
3. extract the zipped archive
4. rename the extracted `d` folder to `e`
5. rename our `d_original` back to `d`

---

The usage of `git above` above creates a zip of the current committed state of subfolder of the active branch, because we use `HEAD`. A specific subfolder from a specific branch can be zipped using the following command

```
git archive -o subfolder.zip BRANCH_NAME path/to/subfolder
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`cd` into the directory `d` and do

```
$ git checkout-index --prefix=e/ -- *
```

to find everything tracked by git in `d` copied to `e` (`e` is relative to the repo root).